# Should I unplug the timer on the water heater when shutting off water to the house?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, timer

If I shut the water off to the house, do I need to unplug the timer on the water heater?

Comment: could this be answered before tomorrow morning please?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother unless you're going to have your water turned off for a couple days.  In that case, turn off the water heater itself.  You'll have a hard time using any hot water with the main turned off, so it is mainly a consideration of whether or not it's worth it to keep the water in the tank hot over the period you won't be using it.

Comment: @judileonard:  You can keep the timer on so it maintains the proper time day when the water comes back on.  But please shut off the fuel (gas, propane, or electric) to the water heater while there is no water.  Also, turn off the water valve at the water heater to prevent water siphoning out.